# How to merge two objects in edit mode without shading and UV errors?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, edit-mode

So I've been modelling a club chair and i need to connect these two together without causing shading errors:

[image]

I tried merging vertices, but it causes shading errors which cannot be fixed via edge split and subsurface and would most likely impact the texture quality:

[image]

None of the other suggested other questions really answer what i need, any way i can merge these two parts together without shading issues?

Comment: @Sava no i didn't think of that. Thanks for the answer it worked out :)

Comment: I'll make it an answer then delete this comment, and you can upvote and accept the answer. I get reputation on the site and people who have similar problems will find the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to merge those two mesh is by using a Edge Loop to connect them together. That way you avoid all the shading and UV errors.